# history push state doesn't work chromium

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the history using the function

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'index.php?'+urlstring +'query=true&file=index&module={$MODULE}&action={$MODULE}Ajax&ajax=true&search=true');
```

in the next code

```
new Ajax.Request(
    'index.php',
    {queue: {position: 'end', scope: 'command'},
        method: 'post',
        postBody:urlstring +'query=true&file=index&module={$MODULE}&action={$MODULE}Ajax&ajax=true&search=true',
        onComplete: function(response) {
                    $("status").style.display="none";
                                result = response.responseText.split('&#&#&#');<!--juan-->
                                $('bfCache').value = $('bfCache').value + result[2];
                                $("ListViewContents").innerHTML= result[2];
                                if(result[1] != '')
                   alert(result[1]);
                $('basicsearchcolumns').innerHTML = '';
                history.pushState(null, null, 'index.php?'+urlstring +'query=true&file=index&module={$MODULE}&action={$MODULE}Ajax&ajax=true&search=true');

        }
       }
    );
```

. When I test my back button in Firefox this works, but in Chromium that doesn't work (I get ERR_CACHE_MISS). Could you help me please?